# Using rand in a seed?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a seeder that should create between 1 and 3 users per product.

```
  Product::factory(100)
            ->hasUsers(rand(1, 3))
            ->create();
```

Unfortunately `rand` only appears to fire once and whatever value is randomly decided, it gets used for every `product`.

For example, if it's 3, then every product will have 3 users.

I'm trying to make it random so some products have 3 users, some have 2 and some have 1.

What's going wrong?

Comment: `->hasUsers()` is being called once, and equates to `Product::factory(100)->hasUsers(1)->create()` (or 2 or 3); it's not a callback that runs `rand()` each time. I'm not sure if this would be the correct approach, but you could do `Product::factory(1)->hasUsers(rand(1, 3))->create()` 100 times (in a Loop, for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rand(1, 3)` is only getting called once, as `hasUsers()` is being called. Think of the factory kind of like a query builder.

To minimize cycles, I would make 3 factory statements with an even split between the number of users.

```
Product::factory(33)->hasUsers(1)->create();
Product::factory(33)->hasUsers(2)->create();
Product::factory(33)->hasUsers(3)->create();
```

Same answer as Tim Lewis

---

If the randomness factor is really important, you can have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories#sequences. Where you could use a sequence that accepts a callback. (This is of course, provided you use a recent enough version of eloquent factories)

Comment: *"Same answer as Tim Lewis"* - Same idea, yes; yours guarantees 100 Products (well, 99) with an even split of 1, 2 and 3 Users. My approach would be 100 Products, with a random split of 1, 2, or 3 Users; panthro can decide which is appropriate to use  But overall, nice answer!

Comment: Yeah, you are correct, the solutions are different. I should have specified that the explination was what i based my answer off of.
Thank you, and i hope i gave credit in some kind of proper way. This was my first time answering. Cheers! :)